# How to increase the width of columns of a DataGrid in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am using DataGrid control in VB.
I have created a DataTable at runtime and added 5 columns in this Datatable.
I binded the data table with DataGrid control.

Width of DataGrid is 880.
The default width of 5 columns of data table in DataGrid is 100. So for 5 columns width used = 500. So an empty space of 380 left at the right hand cornor of DataGrid. I want to fill this empty space with these 5 columns. I want to increase the width of columns so that it fully covered in DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [DataGrid.PreferredColumnWidth Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.preferredcolumnwidth.aspx) property.

```
DataGrid1.PreferredColumnWidth = 176
```

In this case, 176 is 880 / 5.

This value may get overriden if the data in a column is more than 176, however.

You may also want to look at:

[DataGridTableStyle Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtablestyle%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[DataGridColumnStyle Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle.aspx)